# Best practice in server side vs client side coding

Tags: client-side, server-side

I have many situations where I make AJAX call to server side to get some data. My question is:

Is it better to get the data back simply as JSON or XML, but then I need to use javascript to do all the input and it is impossible to use my server side variables of the user in this javascript (am I wrong here) or is it better to get back not only the database data but the whole HTML.

The first way would be to get back from AJAX call only the content of the table cells and do the whole table generating HTML in javascript. The second would be to call AJAX and get the whole HTML with the data in back from server side.

I am using the second approach now because it is easier for me to program in server side language, but I see two problems using this approach:

1. Instead of getting only the data I get whole HTML back, which means for example that I am loading too much data every time instead of generating it on client.
2. The data that I get back is only good for this particular "project", because it is already "formatted" with HTML code. If I would get the JSON raw data, I could reuse the serverside AJAX code to do something else with this data on some other page.

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score -1):

Do not attempt to get HTML or any markup from server to display on the screen. This is a bad practice.

Also, I would prefer JSON to XML.

**EDIT:**
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: So is there any way to build HTML with server side from AJAX JSON or is the only (proper) way to do HTML in javascript using document.write? How do I get my server side variables into javascript then?

Comment: @Jerry2 There is, using JavaScript Abstraction and DOM library JQuery's load() http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Comment: Yes but if I use the load to get whole HTML in, then I am using method 2 which I do. If I get only the Json data with load, I have to use javascript to contruct HTML. And in using Javascript I will have to use some other LOAD to load me the server side variables I already have on this page but on server side :-(

Comment: sorry, but i do not agree that this is a bad practice, especially that twitter, facebook, airbnb are doing this now. True, in 2012, you better of doing normal json work, in 2014 - its more about server side processing, plus "holy grail"